# django IntegerField and SmallIntegerFields maps to the same db type on Oracle

Tags: python, django, oracle, orm, django-orm

Does anyone knows the reason why `IntegerField` and `SmallIntegerFields` both map to `NUMBER(11,0)` in Oracle?

I would expect `SmallIntegerFiled` to map to something smaller.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for [`PositiveIntegerField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1151) and [`SmallIntegerField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1180) you will see that they are simply derivatives of a normal [`Integer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L980) field with some restrictions. You can see how these python field objects map to Oracle database field type here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/oracle/creation.py#L9

Comment: This doesn't answer my question why Integer ans SmallInteger have the same size. And the answer is not in code - this is some kind of strange design decision or mistake.

Comment: Yea, I misread your question. I'll leave this here as it's interesting to look at the mappings. It looks like it might be an oversight - maybe because oracle leaves the size designation up the to the user, (i.e. there's no `smallint` datatype etc.) it was overlooked. It might be worth submitting a bug. You could also modify the backend yourself and use that.